# strcpy produced duplicated storage items

Tags: c, string, memory, struct

In my program, I'm using strcpy to store a a file line by lines into the appropriate field of a struct array. When I read the the input before storing, it is right so I must be using an incorrect/unsafe/bad method to move data from the stored input to the struct variable. Here is the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>      /* for printf() and fprintf() */
#include <sys/socket.h> /* for socket() and bind() */
#include <arpa/inet.h>  /* for sockaddr_in and inet_ntoa() */
#include <stdlib.h>     /* for atoi() and exit() */
#include <string.h>     /* for memset() */
#include <unistd.h>     /* for close() */
#include "./book.h"
#ifndef fileget_C
#define fileget_C
#endif // fileget_C

 void readlib(Book* Library){
  /*char stock[4][125];*/
  FILE *bookfile=fopen("/home/ninja/Sockets/bookstock.txt","r+");


  size_t len=0;
  int num;
  ssize_t read;
  char *stringin;


  int n;
  for(n=0; n<4; n=n+1){
  getline(&stringin, &len, bookfile); 
  strcpy(Library[n].isbn,stringin);
  //printf("%s",Library[n].isbn);/*working print statement*/
  stringin=NULL;

  getline(&stringin, &len, bookfile);
  strcpy(Library[n].Author,stringin);
  //printf("%s",Library[n].Author);
  stringin=NULL;

  getline(&stringin, &len, bookfile);
  strcpy(Library[n].title,stringin);
  //printf("%s",Library[n].title);
  stringin=NULL;

  getline(&stringin, &len, bookfile);
  num=atoi(stringin);
  Library[n].edition=num;
  //printf("%d\n",Library[n].edition);
  stringin=NULL;

  getline(&stringin, &len, bookfile);
  Library[n].year=atoi(stringin);
  stringin=NULL;
  //printf("%d\n",Library[n].year);

  getline(&stringin, &len, bookfile);
  strcpy(Library[n].publisher,stringin);
  stringin=NULL;
  //printf("%s",Library[n].publisher);

  getline(&stringin, &len, bookfile);
  Library[n].inventory=atoi(stringin);
  stringin=NULL;
  //printf("%d",Library[n].inventory);

  getline(&stringin, &len, bookfile);
  Library[n].available=atoi(stringin);
  //printf("%d\n",Library[n].available);

  }
  // printf("%s",Library[0].title);
  //printf("%s",Library[1].title);
  //printf("%s",Library[2].title);
  //printf("%s\n",Library[3].title);

  // printf("%s",Library[0].Author);
  //printf("%s",Library[1].Author);
  //printf("%s",Library[2].Author);
  //printf("%s",Library[3].Author);

  for(n=0; n<4; n=n+1){
    printf("%s",Library[n].isbn);
    //printf("%s",Library[n].Author);
    //printf("%s\n",Library[n].title);
    //printf("%d\n",Library[n].edition);
    //printf("%d\n",Library[n].year);
    //printf("%s\n",Library[n].publisher);


   // printf("%d\n",Library[n].inventory);
   // printf("%d\n",Library[n].available);

    }

}
```

and here is the output

```
9780132126953
9780123745408
9780133354690
9780072467505
9780132126953Andrew Tanenbaum, David Wetherall
Computer Networks
9780123745408Michael Donahoo, Kenneth Calvert
9780133354690William Stallings
9780072467505Yale Patt, Sanjay Patel
```

When I copy the string, it seems like it might be writing to an adjacent memory area hence one string being appended to another. Here is the text file that goes with it

```
9780132126953
Andrew Tanenbaum, David Wetherall
Computer Networks
5
2011
Prentice-Hall
5
2
9780123745408
Michael Donahoo, Kenneth Calvert
TCP/IP Sockets in C
2
2009
Morgan Kaufman
3
0
9780133354690
William Stallings
Cryptography and Network Security
6
2014
Prentice-Hall
3
3
9780072467505
Yale Patt, Sanjay Patel
Introduction to Computing System from bits & gates to C & beyond
2
2004
McGraw-Hill
1
0
```

Here is what calls fileget

```
  #include <stdio.h>      /* for printf() and fprintf() */
#include <sys/socket.h> /* for socket() and bind() */
#include <arpa/inet.h>  /* for sockaddr_in and inet_ntoa() */
#include <stdlib.h>     /* for atoi() and exit() */
#include <string.h>     /* for memset() */
#include <unistd.h>     /* for close() */
#include "./DieWithError.c"
#define ECHOMAX 255     /* Longest string to echo */
#include "./fileget.c"
#include "./climsg.h"

void DieWithError(char *errorMessage);  /* External error handling function */

void main()
{
    Book Library[4];

    readlib(Library);
    int n;
    for(n=0; n<4; n=n+1){
        //printf("%s",Library[n].isbn);
       // printf("%s\n",Library[n].Author);
       // printf("%s\n",Library[n].title);
        //printf("%s\n",Library[n].publisher);
       // printf("%d\n",Library[n].year);
        //printf("%d\n",Library[n].edition);
        //printf("%d\n",Library[n].inventory);
       // printf("%d\n",Library[n].available);

    }

    /* book’s validated ISBN-13*/




    int sock;                        /* Socket */
    struct sockaddr_in echoServAddr; /* Local address */
    struct sockaddr_in echoClntAddr; /* Client address */
    unsigned int cliAddrLen;         /* Length of incoming message */
    ClientMessage echoBuffer;        /* Buffer for echo string */
    unsigned short echoServPort=9836;     /* Server port */
    int recvMsgSize;                 /* Size of received message */





    /* Create socket for sending/receiving datagrams */
    if ((sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) < 0)
        DieWithError("socket() failed");

    /* Construct local address structure */
    memset(&echoServAddr, 0, sizeof(echoServAddr));   /* Zero out structure */
    echoServAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;                /* Internet address family */
    echoServAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY); /* Any incoming interface */
    echoServAddr.sin_port = htons(echoServPort);      /* Local port */

    /* Bind to the local address */
    if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &echoServAddr, sizeof(echoServAddr)) < 0)
        DieWithError("bind() failed");

    for (;;) /* Run forever */
    {
        /* Set the size of the in-out parameter */


        /* Block until receive message from a client */
        recvfrom(sock, &echoBuffer, sizeof(echoBuffer), 0,(struct sockaddr *) &echoClntAddr, &cliAddrLen);
        char *request;
        if( echoBuffer.requestType==0)
            request="QUERY \n";
        if (echoBuffer.requestType==1)
            request="BORROW \n";
        if (echoBuffer.requestType==2)
            request="RETURN \n";



        /*printf("%s", "message received \n");*/
        /* Send received datagram back to the client */
        //sendto(sock, &echoBuffer, recvMsgSize, 0,
               //(struct sockaddr *) &echoClntAddr, sizeof(echoClntAddr));

    }
    /* NOT REACHED */
}
```

and this is the header for my book struct

```
#ifndef BOOK_H
#define BOOK_H

typedef struct examp
{
    char isbn[13];
    char Author[34];
    char title[65];
    int  edition;
    int year;
    char publisher [14];
    int  inventory;
    int available;


} Book;


#endif // BOOK_
```

Comment: Please remove all code that is not necessary to reproduce your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please properly indent your code

Comment: Please show us how you use this `readlib` function, what are you passing to it? How is that pointer initialized?

Comment: ..ans show declarations for data, eg. the Book typedef.  Data is more imprtant than code, so show it.

Answer (score 2):

When you define a local variable in C, it's not initialized, its value is *indeterminate*. Using such a variable (except to initialize it) will lead to *undefined behavior*. This is what happens when you do the first call to `getline` where the variable `stringin` is not initialized.

You also have several memory leaks, since the `getline` function allocates memory for you, which you do not `free`.

Furthermore, you have not error checking, like checking if the file opened successfully or you could actually read anything, or checking if there's an early end of the file.

Comment: Worse - stringin set to NULL after, so auto-leak :(

Answer (score 1):

One problem is that the buffer `stringin` is uninitialised, and may be pointing all over the place.  Here's a [guide to using getline](http://c-for-dummies.com/blog/?p=1112).  You correctly set `stringin` to `NULL` several times, but you missed setting it before it's first used.

On reading the code more carefully, there's a problem with the size of the character arrays in the Book typedef.  You are trying to put a 13 character string into `char isbn[13]`.  But strings are NUL-terminated, and so strcpy writes 14 characters to the `isbn`.  Depending on how the compiler packs the structure, the terminating NUL may be overwriting the next element in the structure.  This would explain what you are seeing I think.

To fix this, you need to do a couple of things: allocate enough storage; don't just copy everything you get into the struct, but only as much as will fit (hint: use `strlcpy` or `strncpy`, and ensure the last character of the buffer is set to NUL), and check for errors.  Reject the input if it doesn't pass tests, such as if it's too long.  Remember you can use `sizeof` to find the length of the buffer instead of hard-coding it.

Comment: I''m not getting any problems until i go to print what is actually in the struct array. It prints the isbn field fine but the strcpy state is what gets wonky.

Comment: I forgot to add that that printing stringing after each getline actually outputs the correct string. It only starts getting weird after I use strcpy and print them from the stored strict array

Comment: I've changed the answer a lot after reading the code more carefully.

Comment: fixed the problem. extended isbn to 14 characters and added null terminator to end of all string. since the isbn and author were in adjacent memory addresses, the printf statement would continue on to print both isbn and author fields until it reached a null terminator.